# NSString copy property does not work

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring

I have a class like this:

```
@interface DataModel : NSObject {
    NetworkClient *networkClient_;
    NSString *lastIp;
    int lastPort;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NetworkClient *networkClient_;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastIp;
...
```

And in some place I'm writing:

```
[DataModel sharedDataModel].lastIp = addressField_.text;
NSString *temp = [DataModel sharedDataModel].lastIp;
```

And the `tepm` string is nil. What's the problem ?

PS: I've made @synthesise

Comment: If your object can be modified in more than one thread at a time, I would recommend to make the property atomic.

Comment: If temp is nil then either addressField_.text is nil, [DataModel sharedDataModel] returns nil or [DataModel sharedDataModel] returns different instances.

Comment: @Jason addressField_.text is not nil. sharedDataModel return the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DataModel sharedDataModel].lastIp = addressField_.text;
NSString *temp = [DataModel sharedDataModel].lastIp;
```

`temp` will be nil if any of `addressField_`, `addressField_.text`, or `[DataModel sharedDataModel]` either are nil or return nil.   Alternatively, if `[DataModel sharedDataModel]` returns a different instance that hasn't initialized `lastIp`.

Log and/or check every single one of those items;  you'll find a `nil` somewhere where you don't expect it.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in [DataModel sharedDataModel]. I've been reseting lastIp property.